# Does electric potential give electron mass as same as higgs field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, potential, dirac-equation, higgs

Inside negatively charged ball there is constant electric potential. If electron will be placed inside ball with constants potential will it give mass from electric potential as same as higgs field give mass?

Comment: The higgs mechamism  is more complicated than the discusions and videos found on the net.  The rest  masses of the elementary particles in the table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle are acquired once off at symmetry breaking ot the weak interaction at  cosmological tmes http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html and do not depend on the locations and fields after that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such effect in EM theory. EM mass arises due to self-force, a result of electromagnetic interactions within the system. Thus if we study composite charged body, its mass is greater than sum of masses of its charged parts. It turns out this additional EM mass is proportional to electrostatic energy of the system.

So your negatively charged electron does not acquire additional mass due to being inside the ball, but the whole system ball + electron does have greater mass when they are together than if they were far from each other.